# Why is Croatia so strong in 2018 FIFA WC?

Tags: world-cup, fifa

Notably, Croatia has a very small population.

What is the reason behind Croatian Football team so strong in 2018?

Comment: Uruguay is even smaller, and is a world' power on football. China is a world power on "everything" but football. Size clearly has no relation to football strength.

Comment: If this question was elaborated upon, I don't see the difference between this and a similar question where population is the reason for ranking https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/is-there-an-objective-reason-for-scandinavian-ice-hockey-ranking, though I understand this question is asking why a team is good given a small population.

Comment: This question has an answer here: [Why is the Croatian football team so successful despite having a population of only 4 million people?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/why-is-the-croatian-football-team-so-successful-despite-having-a-population-of-o)